# C++ Move Semantics: appending the matrix referenced by a unique_ptr to a vector

Tags: c++, move-semantics, armadillo

I have an [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) matrix that is referenced by a `unique_ptr`.  I want to append this matrix to a vector of matrices, without copying the underlying data.

So far, I have the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<arma::mat> m = ...; // Assume this is populated somewhere
std::vector<arma::mat> vec;
vec.push_back(std::move(*m));
```

I think this will do the following:

1. Access the underlying `arma::mat` object (`*m`)
2. Make this object an rvalue (`std::move`)
3. Append the object to the vector without copying it (because it is now an rvalue)

Is this correct, or did I miss something here?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct, or did I miss something here?

Yes, it is correct.

There are several disadvantages.

1. At final point `m` refers a died object. Accessing it may be dangerous.
2. Object of type `arma::mat` is enough heavy. Look at encapsulated local storage for small vectors and matrices. It disables moving semantic for small matrices and vectors.
3. Resizing of `std::vector<arma::mat>`, manipulating with its elements, is weighty due to the same local storage for small objects.

I would prefer the code like bellow

```
std::unique_ptr<arma::mat> m = ...; // Assume this is populated somewhere
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<arma::mat>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::move(m));
```

Comment: Yet this adds another level of indirection which incurs some performance overhead. I think it really depends. If the vector is frequently read, but seldom written to, storing pointers may not be a good idea.

Comment: In a related question, what if I do `std::unique_ptr<arma::mat> m = ...; arma::mat a = std::move(*m)`.  Would this move the object inside of the unique ptr to variable a, without copying the date?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it would move the object. The close behavior can be reached with several expressions: `arma::mat a(std::move(*m));` or `arma::mat a; a.swap(*m);` or `arma::mat a; m->swap(a);` or `arma::mat a; std::swap(a, *m);`.

Comment: Wow, this is very powerful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct. But there is still room for improvement. Specifically,

```
vec.push_back(std::move(*std::exchange(m, nullptr)));
```

This releases the pointer immediately. That means the moved-from object is uninitialized (destructor called) with storage deallocated right on spot. This may provide some performance benefit (the same argument discussed [here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html) applies).